# Is there a way to filter Playa relationship in {exp:gmap:results}?

Tags: add-on, playa, google-maps-for-ee

One of the "filters" so to speak on my gmap search is a playa field. Is there a way to filter my results by that relationship? I tried running the `{exp:playa:parents}` loop inside the `{results}` but naturally, it is a double loop. If on the search form, I only want parents of entry_id 1, how would I go about that? The data is in the post var, but I need to get the playa parents loop combined with the results loop - else I'll tear in to PHP.

Answer (score 1):

While it wasn't as clean of a solution as I wanted, I ended up using categories rather than a Playa relationship. Does the trick, but now I have a category group acting as a channel.